# React Native getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, request

want to do a

```
document.getElementById('js-pjax-loader-bar')
```

from https://github.com/facebook/react-native

And i don't know how o get it!

I try:

```
const jsCode = "document.getElementById('js-pjax-loader-bar')";
return (     
  <WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
    onMessage={this._onMessage}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode }
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
);
```

Possibly the script run, but i don't know how to get de result.

Comment: Where do you see `document.getElementById` in those docs?  You probably want to `export` and `import` what you're trying to pass around.

Comment: @Icaro Rios: I need your solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you need set javaScriptEnabled property as true and use a setTimeout to wait while DOM load.

```
const jsCode = "setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('js-pjax-loader-bar');}, 2000)";
```

And the WebView

```
<WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true}  
    source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
    onMessage={this._onMessage}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode }
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
/>
```

Too can add a alert inside the jsCode to test.

to recive on _onMessage function you need use a window.postMessage

```
const jsCode = "setTimeout(function(){window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('js-pjax-loader-bar')),'https://github.com/facebook/react-native');}, 2000)";
```

and the _onMessage must be like

```
_onMessage(data) {
    var element = JSON.parse(data.nativeEvent.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React is a virtual dom , and generate bundle after rendering (client side rendering) for use ids or something like that is better to use `ref` in react